# Recursion - Python question, return value question

Tags: python, recursion

**I am having a problem with solving the question below.

Implement the sum_positive_numbers function, as a recursive function that returns the sum of all positive numbers between the number n received and 1. For example, when n is 3 it should return 1+2+3=6, and when n is 5 it should return 1+2+3+4+5=15.**

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
    return 0

print(sum_positive_numbers(3)) # Should be 6
print(sum_positive_numbers(5)) # Should be 15
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember always to add a breaking condition. The zero evaluation in this case

```py
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
    if n == 0:
        return n
    return n + sum_positive_numbers(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
    # The base case is n being smaller than 1
    if n < 1:
        return n


    return n + sum_positive_numbers(n - 1)
    # What got me was n - 1. I was using + until I went to the below website to see visualize it

print(sum_positive_numbers(3)) # Should be 6
print(sum_positive_numbers(5)) # Should be 15
```

This is the website I use to visualize code that helps me solve the problem(s). It forces me not to just get an answer from google search, but work through each error, and learn as I go:
[Python Visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion

```
def sum_positive_numbers(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0

    return n + sum_positive_numbers(n-1)

print(sum_positive_numbers(3)) # Should be 6
print(sum_positive_numbers(5)) # Should be 15
```